# Short "run" dialog box commands

Tags: windows-xp

When I hit Windows+R, I can type in calc and get a calculator really quickly. Same thing for mspaint. My question is, how do I adjust this so I can type "netbeans" and have it open the program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest option would be to add the following location to [your path variable](http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/environment.htm):

```
C:\Program Files\NetBeans X.X.X\bin
```

replace X.X.X with your version of Netbeans.

Alternatively you could make a shortcut to the netbeans.exe executable in the above path, and place that shortcut in a location thats already in your path (e.g. `C:\Windows\System32`).

Comment: Oh yeah. I like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can DIY a specified folder as a PATH ,and create your executive programs' shortcut(.lnk) into the folder.

So the .lnk's name is the command you typed into the RUN dialog box when you want to launch it.